# Question about $f$ continuous function with these conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, infinity

Suppose I have a differentiable and bounded function 
$$f: [0, + \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ such that 
$$\forall x \in [0, + \infty) \, :  f(x) \cdot f'(x) > \sin x.$$

The question is: does it follow that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$$necessarily exists?

Thanks for any suggestions and comments, even modify some conditions of the problem.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but a suggestion might be to consider $g(x)=[f(x)]^2$. Then $g'(x)=2f'(x)f(x)>2\sin(x)$ if $f(x)$ is a function with the properties listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g(u) =(f(u))^2 +2\cdot \cos u $ is increasing and bounded hence there exists $\lim_{u\to \infty } g(u) $ hence $\lim_{u\to \infty } f(u) $ cannot exist.

Comment: That's a nice way of using the fact that $\lim_{u \to \infty}\cos u$ does not exist. (+1)